# telerik's radcontrols cause cross thread exception

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, rad-controls

I am using Telerik's radcontrols for winforms.

Here is a program that can reproduce my problem:

```
public partial class RadForm1 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public RadForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadMessageBox.SetThemeName("Office2010Black");
        RadMessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        //MessageBox.Show("hello world");
        run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() => run2());
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void run2()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("hello");
        RadMessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

Whenever try using Telerik's messagebox I am getting a cross thread exception.  However if I use the standard winform messagebox instead then it will work absolutely fine.

Maybe i am missing something here.

UPDATE:

for anyone else having the same problem this is the link to offical reply [Click here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/forms-and-dialogs/radmessagebox---error-when-opening-multiple-instances.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winform `MessageBox` class is specifically designed to be able to be called from a non-UI thread.

The `RadMessageBox` simply wasn't.  It was designed under the assumption that it would be called from the UI thread.

Comment: well....the above is just a sample code that i made to reproduce the problem.Calling controls from UI thread would require significant tweaking in my production code.

Comment: @WinCoder Yes, I would imagine.  That's why I didn't provide you with code when you asked for a solution; how you go about ensuring that the method is run from the UI thread will be dependent on context you haven't described.  You should be treating it like any other UI interaction from the point of view of the design of your application.  It needs to be run in the UI thread, it should be separated from the business logic, etc.  If that would require significant rework it probably is indicative of an underlying design flaw.

Comment: you are absolutely right sepration of concerns is very central to the idea of good coding. However i am an absolute noob so i find it difficult to realize. Anyways i will try improving upon on my code and thanks for the help.